# whats the difference between $|v|$ and $||v||$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, normed-spaces

$v$ being a vector.
I never understood what they mean and haven't found online resources. Just a quick question.

Thought it was absolute and magnitude respectively when regarding vectors. need confirmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double bar indicates the magnitude of the vector. In essence algebraically that is still the absolute value, meaning the square root of $x^2+y^2$ (in case of 2D)

Answer (score 5):

In general $\lvert\cdot\rvert$ and $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ are both used to signify [*norms*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) of some sort. Different texts use different notation conventions, and sometimes the precise definition (if there *is* one) will vary from context to context

Answer (score 2):

I have found $|\cdot|$ to almost always represent the euclidean ($2$)-norm of a vector in $\mathbb K^n$, and $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ is a general sign for a norm. In different context, both may be used for different norms, though. I have even seen $|||\cdot |||$ for a "special" norm